# Rendered more hooks than during the previous render. getting this error tried almost everything in order to fix it not getting whats the problem

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
export const TokenExpiration = () => {
    const {t} = useTranslation()
    const [openDiscardModal, setOpenDiscardModal] = useState(false)
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false)

    const redirectToLogin = () => {
        setIsLoading(true)
        window.location.href = '/login'
    }

    const showPopupTokenExpired = (event) => {
        if (event && event.message.includes('Invalid token specified')) {
            Notification.showError(event.message)
            redirectToLogin()
        }
        if (isTokenExpired() && window.location.pathname !== '/login') {
            setOpenDiscardModal(true)
        }
    }

    const interValId = setInterval(() => {
        showPopupTokenExpired()
    }, 1000)

    useEffect(() => {
        return () => clearInterval(interValId)
    }, [])

    const discardModal = {
        buttonCount: 1,
        buttonStyles: [
            { background: '#474747', color: 'white', border: 'none', margin: '5px' },
        ],
        buttonTexts: ['Back to login'],
        buttonActions: [() => redirectToLogin()],
        alertText: 'Token Expired',
        alertMessage: 'Your Token is Expired. Please login again to continue',
        buttonIcons: [
            isLoading ? (
                <Spinner animation="border" role="status" size="sm" key="spinner" />
            ) : null,
        ],
    }

    window.addEventListener('error', (event) => {
        showPopupTokenExpired(event) // Check token expiration on error event
    })

    return (
        <ConfirMationModal
            openConfirmationModal={openDiscardModal}
            setOpenConfirmationModal={setOpenDiscardModal}
            popupParams={discardModal}
        />
    )
}
```

this is a pretty simple component but here i am getting an error  Rendered more hooks than during the previous render.  not sure why but when i remove the usetranslation hooks then it wokrs just fine

i have tried many things passing t as a props then also i am facing this issue i am expecting it to work like a normal componenet in react

Comment: I think it would be good to see from where you are importing useTranslation hook and if it is your custom hook the post the code, since you think the problem comes from that hook.

Comment: no, it is of react-i18next for translating text

Comment: Post the code for ConfirmatioModal, Spinner, isTokenExpired(). It is recommended to provide example, which can be reproduced. I will reproduce your code and debug the problem.